# Changing Data type on Google Big Query: Date Field Error

Tags: google-bigquery

I have created a query to change the data type of the `Date` column from `String` to `Date`

the query used is the following:

```
SELECT *, CAST(Date AS DATE) From `table_name`
```

However, when running the query I am receiving the following error:

> Invalid date: '18/11/2020'

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PARSE_DATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#parse_date) instead:

```
SELECT 
  * EXCEPT (Date),
  PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', Date) AS Date 
From table_name
```

or

```
SELECT 
  Account,
  Campaign_name,
  PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', Date) AS Date,
  Ad_set_name,
  Ad_name,
  Impressions,
  Cost__GBP_,
  Link_clicks,
  Reach,
  Website_conversions
From table_name
```

Comment: HI I have used your suggested query but I have got the following error: Mismatch between format character '/' and string character '2'

Comment: Hi, probably not all rows have a format of `18/11/2020`. Try to use `SAFE.PARSE_DATE` instead. It will produce NULL for the not parsed rows. Thus you'll be able to find and fix such rows.

Comment: HI, I have used your query but is creating an additional column called f0 instead of overwriting the existing "Date" field from string to date data type.                                                                                      Have you got any suggestions on how maintaining the same number of columns and overwriting the existing Date field schema?

Comment: Schema Here:                                                                                                   Account STRING NULLABLE 
Campaign_name STRING NULLABLE 
Date STRING NULLABLE 
Ad_set_name STRING NULLABLE 
Ad_name STRING NULLABLE 
Impressions INTEGER NULLABLE 
Cost__GBP_ FLOAT NULLABLE 
Link_clicks FLOAT NULLABLE 
Reach FLOAT NULLABLE 
Website_conversions FLOAT NULLABLE 
f0_ DATE NULLABLE

Comment: Try EXCEPT or list all necessary fields explicitly. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The casting of String to Date in Standard SQL in BigQuery has to be performed for string in format YYYY-MM-DD according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_rules#casting_date_types).

Your string is in a different format and couldn't be casted by CAST function.

Try [PARSE_DATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#parse_date) function in BigQuery. An example would be parsed in the following way:

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE("%d/%m/%Y", "18/11/2020") as parsed;
```